# Converting a DAG where the nodes represent tasks and the connections represent dependencies into something suitable for parallel computing

Tags: c++, multithreading, graph-theory, directed-acyclic-graphs

I've got a DAG (Directed Acyclic Graph) derived from a [sparse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) [strictly-lower-triangular-square-matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix). There is a task associated with every row of the matrix. The matrix entries are dependencies -- means enforcing order of the tasks. Every task is read-only accessing results calculated by the tasks it depends on. Obviously there are tasks, which do not depend on any other tasks -- e.g. the task matching the first row as it does not have any entries in the strictly-lower-triangular-matrix.
The value of any entry in the sparse matrix does not matter -- only that there is an entry or not.
Tasks can execute in parallel as long as the matching dependencies (tasks) have been executed.

How can this be converted into something suitable for parallel processing?

I already tried the following:

1. collecting all the rows without any entry in the strictly-lower-triangular matrix, which obviously don't have any dependencies. I called this start rows.
2. Using a std::vector< std::atomic< std::size_t> > initialized with the number of incoming edges for every task. Decrementing the entry matching an outgoing connection after a task is finished and upon reaching zero starting the matching task.

**This approach yields code, which is busy mainly with decrementing std::atomic< std::size_t > and slower than the serial version (for one not small example).**
I was wondering if someone could suggest a better approach.
I was thinking of partitioning the graph into subgraphs of simpler structure -- combining nodes in the original graph into nodes in the new graph.
But I cannot come up with an algorithm implementing this.

There is a question about what this is supposed to do:

Well I could answer that the task associated with any row is a std::function<> object in order to keep this general.
If you need to know -- this is [Gauss-Seidel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Seidel_method) but it could be applied to any task resulting in a DAG.

Come to think of it:

The entire problem is identical to the problem solved by the LINUX utility make:

A topological sort and parallel execution of the tasks which are ready to be executed. The problem is, that the cost of the tasks vary dramatic with many being very cheap and only a few being (very) expensive.

Comment: Please specify what you mean with "parallel processing", i.e. which actions exactly should be executable in a thread-safe way. The suggested architecture depends heavily on that.

Comment: Your description is very confusing.  "There is a task associated with every row/column"  Does each row and column have a unique task?  Or are the tasks associated with the cells?  "collecting all the rows ... I called this start nodes."  You called the rows collected start nodes?!?  How is the task order enforced by a matrix entry?  It would help if you posted a small example and explain what it does.

Comment: I'm referring only to rows now. But one could equally use columns. The matrix is two-dimensional and there is a one-dimensional-vector of tasks, one for each row of the matrix.

Comment: I'd use a thread for each task, only fired when its input data is ready (e.g. by another task). You may keep a handler of "not-ready-to-fire threads".

Comment: One trivial optimization is to combine two serial nodes A and B with B only depending on A or any dependency of A into a single node AB saving one unnecessary synchronization.

Comment: Another optimization is to avoid creating dependencies, which are already indirectly created by other dependencies:

B depends on A, then B does not need to depend on anything A depends on.

Answer (score 0):

Your description is still quite confusing.

My best guess is that if there were two tasks then

| X | task1 | task2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| task1 | - | - |
| task2 | 1 | - |

means that task2 depends on the output from task1

So, your algorithm would be

- Load your matrix into a graph theory library, using a directed graph model
- Loop over vertices, identifying those that have an in-degree of zero.
- Loop over the zero in-degree vertices, grouping together those that share children
- Loop over the groups, submitting each to be processed in ||el

So

| X | task1 | task2 | task3 | task4 | task5 | task6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| task1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| task2 | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |
| task3 | - | - |  |  |  |  |
| task4 | - | - | - |  |  |  |
| task5 | - | - | 1 | 1 |  |  |
| task6 | - | - | - | 1 | - |  |

gives 2 groups that can be independently processed

{ 1, 2 } and ( 3, 4, 5, 6 }

Comment: Could your algorithm be described as finding independent clusters of nodes? 

How would this reduce the number of decrements of std::atomic?

Comment: Depends on how you define a cluster.  If you mean what is usually termed a component, then yes.  Many graph theory libraries will give you this with one call to a method.  The point is that each component can be processed independently ( i.e run in its own thread without having to wait for any other thread )  I do not know what std::atomic has got to do with your problem - it seems irrelevant to me.